# Configure one-off DNS resolution for xip.io address on EC2 instance

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, resolve, xip.io

How can I configure my EC2 instance so that one specific wildcard domain (e.g. `1.2.3.4.xip.io`) resolves to some IP that I've chosen (e.g. `5.6.7.8`), and all other DNS resolution proceeds as usual?

Adding the following line to my `/etc/hosts` file didn't help:

```
5.6.7.8 1.2.3.4.xip.io
```

Answer (score 0):

All systems have a hosts file in which you can override specific DNS lookips. On linux based systems it should be `/etc/hosts`. In windows its somewhere in the windows folder.

The format is very simple, but you want to be careful about deleting anything already in it. Each line is set up as `123.123.123.123 mydomain.com`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't quite work.  I've updated my question with an additional detail.

Comment: This will set the dns resolution for your requests originating from your instance. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I have a "workstation" EC2 instance, a "warden" EC2 instance, and a "router" warden-container inside the "warden" instance (a VM inside another VM).  Let's say the have IPs w.o.r.k, w.a.r.d, and r.o.u.t respectively.  From inside the "warden" VM, I can make requests to the router like so: <host>.r.o.u.t.xip.io.  However the r.o.u.t is not reachable from the rest of the world, in particular I can't reach it from the workstation.  I'd like to be able to make the same request from the workstation VM to the router.

Comment: My current approach is kinda complicated, I'm open to better suggestions.  If I can get r.o.u.t.xip.io to resolve to w.a.r.d on my workstation, and then have nginx running on the warden VM to proxy requests (from <host>.r.o.u.t.xip.io/<path> to <host>.r.o.u.t.xip.io/<path>) then I think this will work.